# Eclipse Help Plugin - Move xml files into a nested directory of a project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, help-system

I use a wizard to create a new Plug-in Project and select the template "Plug-in with sample help content". If I start the created project, the sample table of contents is listed in help view. I want to move the whole bunch of xml and html help-files into a 'help'-directory:

[image: project file structure]

The paths in plugin.xml are changed automatically by eclipse:
[image]

The same for the toc*.xml files:

[image]

The entry `bin.includes` in `build.properties` is changed appropriately as well:
[image]

But the sample table of contents isn't shown anymore if I start eclipse with this plugin. I can't see any exceptions and there are no related messages in error log. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Eclipse Community Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206625/)

What should be fixed were `link_to` attributes in the child tocs:

[image]